# How to declare a "mask" material using A-Frame.js

Tags: three.js, 3d, aframe

I'm trying to make a scene where there's a "hole in the wall". 
[image]

This requires a plane with square removed, and then a material applied to the plane with the following properties:

1. Invisible to the camera
2. Hides any other objects from being rendered that are behind it

There's an example of this with three.js [here](https://stemkoski.github.io/AR-Examples/), but how can I do it with the [a-frame material syntax](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/material.html#sidebar)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The "Mask".

Looking at the [box-hole](https://stemkoski.github.io/AR-Examples/hole-box.html) example, to create the illusion, Lee creates two boxes. 
1) The box which is "in the hole" 
2) A slightly bigger invisible box without a top - to cloak the first one. The top is removed to work as a "hole" through which you can see the first box

### How it can be done in THREE.js

The cloaking is done by preventing the second box from rendering any color. From Lee's example:

```
 let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      colorWrite: false;
 })
```

The [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.colorWrite) state, that the flag can be used to create invisible objects hiding others.

### How it can be done in a-frame

I'm afraid you can't simply make the "cloak" material in a-frame. The `colorWrite` property is not exposed in the `material` component.

What i think the simplest way would be - is creating a `cloak` component, which will create the second box in THREE.js:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('cloak', {
    init: function() {
      let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)
      geometry.faces.splice(4, 2) // cut out the top faces 
      let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
         colorWrite: false
      })
      let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
      mesh.scale.set(1.1, 1.1, 1.1)
      this.el.object3D.add(mesh)
    }
})
```

and use it like this:

```
<a-box material="src: myPic.png; side: back;" cloak>
```

Check it out in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/gftruj/pen/QRgVVp). With a HIRO marker, you should get a hole like this:
[image]

### Using models, or other objects as "cloaks"

Here we need to apply the `colorWrite=false` magic to each node/child of the model.

```
init: function() {
  // make sure the model is loaded first
  this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', e=>{
    let mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh') // grab the mesh
    if (mesh === undefined) return;        // return if no mesh :(
    mesh.traverse(function(node) {         // traverse through and apply settings
      if (node.isMesh && node.material) {  // make sure the element can be a cloak
        node.material.colorWrite = false
        node.material.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Also make sure the cloak is rendered before the elements that needs cloaking:

```
<a-marker>
  <a-entity gltf-model="#wall-with-a-hole" cloak-component></a-entity>
  <!-- the other stuff that needs to be cloaked-->
</a-marker
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. For my need, it would be great to add the "cloak" parameter to a an `<a-entity>` and have it apply the `colorWrite:false` to the whole object. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, is any of these helpful: [cloak on a mesh group with cut out faces](https://jsfiddle.net/bv8j0ty6/2/), [a cloak on two objects switching on/off each second](https://jsfiddle.net/k2e5m7s3/)

Comment: I have a 3D model already like: `<a-entity collada-model="#myshape"></a-entity>` and I'm just wanting to apply the cloak material to it. Can't seem to get it to work :/

Comment: can you provide a glitch, or git repo ?

Comment: Sure: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/90f266fd-8068-4467-9f91-58838a09aedf

There is a model of a plane with a "window" that I want to be the cloak. 

If you look in the assets, I have added the custom marker being used.

Comment: So, line 35 is the item I want to be the "cloak"

Comment: I'll try to check it out once i'm home, is it okay if i remix this and massacre it a bit ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193704/discussion-between-kthornbloom-and-piotr-adam-milewski).